# How to run a cron every 3h with an time interval?

Tags: cron, cron-task

I need to run a php task every 3h all the days from 08:00AM to 10:00PM
Will this work ?

00      8-22/3  *       *       *

Comment: According to `man 5 crontab`, it looks like that will work. Did you try it? Just make a little test `crontab` and use the `date` command as the command. You should get an email to `root` with the date at the times it runs.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Yes, it works well. I was not sure of the "00". But it's ok.